# Super Beginner Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to display the contents of a javascipt script on an html page but I am not sure how to do so? The script is as follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://widget.parishesonline.com/publications?
id=4380d54a4c312f854ea93f3520cf1bf2650642d9"></script>
```

From what I have read, I put the script into the header, but I don't know what javascript code to use to display it on a web page -

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://widget.parishesonline.com/publications?
id=4380d54a4c312f854ea93f3520cf1bf2650642d9"></script> </head>
```

tags but I don't know what to put in the body to display the contents.

Comment: I appreciate being downvoted into oblivion but could someone help?

Comment: What's one the javascript that you want to show? Ho are you planning to show it? `document.xSelector().innerHtml = text` or any similar? The question is unclear?

Comment: Sure I'll help. Have you actually tried putting that script tag in the `<head>` of a page? Because if you have you would have seen that it does all the rest for you and displays itself.

Comment: The typical type of display is an image of each PDF with a link to the PDF. Is there some sort of overarching function that you can put into the xSelector to get everthing from that page?

Comment: A  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the script works just fine. How about trying to use it?
I can't do this on SO so here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1zzvy1h/1/).

Notice there is nothing in the fiddle but the script tag, just like I said in my commment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.parishesonline.com/publications?id=4380d54a4c312f854ea93f3520cf1bf2650642d9"></script>
```

**I guess I can do this on SO**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.parishesonline.com/publications?id=4380d54a4c312f854ea93f3520cf1bf2650642d9"></script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I thought I was going crazy. You solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`script` tags are for interpreted scripts, so by adding it to the `head` tag, you're instructing the browser to load and interpret the script, which has nothing to do with displaying it. You do not need to add anything to the `head` in order to display any content in the `body`.

One way to add remote content to the `body` of your page is using an `iframe` tag:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>I'm showing a script!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://widget.parishesonline.com/publications?id=4380d54a4c312f854ea93f3520cf1bf2650642d9"/>
  </body>
```